# Download file from Dropbox using javascript dropbox api

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, dropbox, dropbox-api

I tried to download a file from Dropbox using Core Api with javascript.
Here is the method I have written.

```
function downloadFile(path) {
    var url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/auto/"+path;
    var result;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, false);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {    
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            result = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.send(path);
}
```

But I am always getting the status as 400. Don't know whats wrong. I got this below HTML as response.

```
<html>
<head><title>400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<center>The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port</center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit 1 :**

```
  var url = "https://api-content.dropbox.com/1/files/auto/" + path;
    var result;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            result = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("access_token",token);
    xhr.send();
```

Comment: seems headers is missing in request

Comment: which header do i need to add ??

Comment: Where in your code are you handling HTTPS? It likely isn't enough to just add in an HTTPS URL and have the API accept it.

Comment: i have given the url with https prefix

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#http-origin    7.3

Comment: could you please tell which header i should include ?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#oa2-authorize   You have to go through Authentication for the API to honor your request, right? Dropbox isn't just going to allow you to download a file because you added an s to a URL, correct? If they would then I would get all of my data an everyone I know's data off of the service as soon as possible. That is why I initially asked you where are you handling HTTPS.

Comment: I have initially gone through the oauth 2 authorize request. I got an access_token as response. Now I tried sending this token as header.
 xhr.setRequestHeader("access_token",token); 
But still the same error.

Comment: What browser are you using? I can't reproduce your error in Chrome. That said, you should be using a GET rather than a POST, you shouldn't send anything in the body, and synchronous XHR is discouraged (passing `false` for the third parameter to `open`).

Comment: As per your suggestion, I have edited my code (See Edit 1 above.). 
But still the same error. I am using chrome.

Comment: I also can't reproduce that error using your latest code, but one thing that looks wrong is the way you're setting the access token. It should be done like: `xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);`

Comment: Thanks Greg for your support. I tried it using the chrome extension rest client api and i got the response. But on calling like xmlhttprequest i am getting status 400. I couldn't find the reason why this is happening.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle with a version of your code that works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/qfwf7uhp/ Here's what I get: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9xjjh9ygkknrf37/Screenshot%202015-07-29%2023.00.28.png?dl=0 Does that work for you if you put in your path and access token?

Comment: Thanks Greg.. In jsfiddle I too got the result. It may be the problem of calling request from localhost.

Comment: Yea, it sounds like something is interfering with your connection. Are you behind a proxy or something?

Comment: Now i am getting the correct response... We are using wakanda ssjs framework. it is having both client side and serverside javascript. We tried from server side and doesn't work. Now calling from client side, it works perfctly. Thanks for your support. Thank you all for your support. :-D